# Adding lists to specific elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, partitions

I have compiled lists of non-diagonal and diagonal entries for a matrix. I'm trying to add elements from the diagonal-entry lists into certain entries of the non-diagonal lists. Is there a feasible way I can add these lists without retyping everything up in a new list? Or should I just try another approach?

I've listed examples of my lists in a much shortened version for simplicity; in reality, I'm trying to create a matrix of size 30x30.
I've tried messing around with the Part[] function, but haven't been able to get it to work the way I desire.

```
non-diags = {{0,0,-1},{0,0,-1},{-1,-1,0}}
diags = {5,4,6}
```

My desired list is:

```
matrixlist = {{5,0,-1},{0,4,-1},{-1,-1,6}}
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
nondiags = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}};
diags = {5, 4, 6};
DiagonalMatrix[diags] + nondiags
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}};

d = {5, 4, 6};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[d &, m, Table[{i, i}, {i, Length @ d}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}};

d = {5, 4, 6};
```

---

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[m, {i_, i_} :> d[[i]]]

(*{{5, 0, -1}, {0, 4, -1}, {-1, -1, 6}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

To *replace* the diagonal of a square matrix with a vector:

```
MapThread[ReplacePart, {nondiags, diags, Range[Length@diags]}]


(* {{5, 0, -1}, {0, 4, -1}, {-1, -1, 6}} *)
```

(Learned from Leonid Shifrin's book, *Mathematica An Advanced Introduction*, pp 269-270, available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org), among many other places)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
nondiags = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}};
diags = {5, 4, 6};

res = MapIndexed[ReplacePart[#1, First@#2 -> diags[[First@#2]]] &, 
  nondiags]
```

---

OR

```
rules = Thread[Table[{i, i}, {i, Length@diags}] -> diags]
ReplacePart[nondiags, rules]
```

(* same result *)

---

*Visualization:*

```
MatrixForm /@ {
  diags
  , nondiags
  , res
  }
```

---

[image]